# Simplest way to assign value labels / categories to existing data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with datasets created by SPSS wherein labels can be added to numeric variables e.g. the numbers 1,2,3 could have the category A, B, C.

For data visualisation it would be useful to reassign these labels once in Pandas.

I have been able to achieve this using the code below but it seems overly complicated to define a new function every time I want to create new labels for existing data.

Is there a more simple approach to achieving this?

```
import pandas as pd 

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'variable':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
                'value':[50, 55, 65, 55,33,66]})

def setCategory(c):
    if c['variable'] == 1:
        return 'A'
    elif c['variable'] == 2:
        return 'B'
    elif c['variable'] == 3:
        return 'C'

sample_df['Category'] = sample_df.apply(setCategory, axis =1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mapping from numbers to letters and use that in [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mapping = dict(zip(range(1, 4), list('ABC')))

mapping
Out: {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}

sample_df['variable'].map(mapping)
Out: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    B
5    C
Name: variable, dtype: object
```